# Copying polygon feature class with 405 features for each matching owner entity?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon-creation, one-to-many

I have 425 polygon features that I need to duplicate in relationship to 5907 owner entities that are contained inside an excel sheet I converted to a table. So each polygon represents a lease record and each lease record has different owner entities associated each lease file number. So for polygon lease file 03457 you have 7 different owner entities related to it. I need to make a copy of the one polygon feature 03457 6 more times to match the owner entities records and provide a polygon feature for each owner entity. The polygon feature and the table showing the owner entities both have lease numbers to associate both together. I tried a relater and it only related all the data for the first record of each lease file number. I feel like there is probably a way to take the polygon features and create copies for each matching lease file number representing the owning entity for each lease file.

Comment: After you Join the Polygons to Owners, save the data to a new feature class. You should have a 1:M join. The table View only shows the first joined record.

Answer (score 2):

The "Make Query Table" tool appears to be what you are looking for:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-query-table.htm

It appears to be a bit quirky, so I would read through the usage carefully.  I've never used it personally but I found this blog post where someone had the same application as you:
https://community.esri.com/thread/30806

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in ArcMap, you need to do a one-to-many join with the Polygon lease number file to the owner information.

Comment: When I tried the One-to-many it did not duplicate the polygon features to match the ownership table data. The polygon feature would pull the first matching record from the table but it would not generate a new polygon feature class for every record found in the ownership table.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not a relate problem. Each join/select needs to be done as a separate step in order to get a shape for each owner/lease combination. I have to do something similar about once a year, picking up polygons that were checked quarterly, so I do 4 separate joins/exports per quarterly cleanup/check date so that I get all polygons that were checked.

I would look into ModelBuilder iteration. It can iterate through field lists or record lists or both. It needs to select for every lease then owner within lease (or perhaps the other way around?).